# How can I filter between two positions in a string?

Tags: python, filter

I have this string:

```
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : Win32_Process
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        :
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
CommandLine      : This is a Example 
                   Hello 789 123 abc
PSComputerName   :
```

But I only want a string from `"This"` to `"abc"` so that my string is:

```
This is a Example Hello 789 123 abc
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This will achieve what you are looking for ONLY if the number of colons (:) before the desired string is the same every time.

```
" ".join([i.strip() for i in bigstring.split(":")[11].split("\n")[:-1]])
```

**Explanation**

1. Split the string up into list using `bigstring.split(":")`
2. Get the 11th element of that list (`'\n__PATH           ', '\nCommandLine      ', ' This is a Example \n                   Hello 789 123 abc\nPSComputerName   '`)
3. Split that string up into a list using `.split("\n")`
4. Use list comprehension to strip the whitespace from all but the last element of that list and put it into a new list.
5. Use `" ".join()` to stick those elements together into the final string.

**Output**

`This is a Example Hello 789 123 abc`

I can't imagine that this is the best way to get the information you are looking for, but without any more context, this is the best I can do.

Answer (score 0):

You could use string indices to split the string into the area you want to use.

### Code:

```
string = """
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : Win32_Process
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        :
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
CommandLine      : This is a Example 
                   Hello 789 123 abc
PSComputerName   :"""

print_string_1 = string[int(len("""__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : Win32_Process
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        :
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
CommandLine      : """)):286]



print(print_string_1 )
```

### Output:

```
 This is a Example
                   Hello 789 123 abc
Process finished with exit code 0
```